# Validate two properties against each other in ASP.NET MVC2, with DataAnnotations

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

For example, I'd like to validate a user registration form and check whether user has entered his password in "password" and "confirm password" fields, AND that those two values are the same.

Found [this](http://byatool.com/mvc/custom-data-annotations-with-mvc-how-to-check-multiple-properties-at-one-time/) but is reflection really the only way?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.CustomValidation(typeof(Test), "Verify", ErrorMessage = "No match!")]
public class Test
{
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public static ValidationResult Verify(Test t)
    {
        if (t.Password == t.ConfirmPassword)
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        else
            return new ValidationResult("");
    }
}
```